# Hover / parent/ child + :before

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

Good morning, everyone,

I have a problem with my css/javascript.

Here is the URL of the problem site: https://www.espace-musculation.com/nutrition-sportive/

I set up a: before on a link to have all the div of the top clickable:

```
z-index: 2; 
happy:''; 
position: absolute; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
top: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
background-color: rgba (0,0,0,0,0);
```

I'd like to add a shadow on the image with: hover over the image when hovering, but I still haven't found a solution.

If someone has an idea in css or js I'm a taker!

Thank you, thank you!

Comment: Which image?  the one in the header?

Comment: you can use hover in jquery. here's the link https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear that for which image you are talking about. But for current situation I would suggest to use following code in the same div/img tag class where you need to put shadow:

CSS:

```
 -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Will this work for you?